# Creating partitions of sets such that each partition is the same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, discrete-mathematics

As per the title I am trying to write a function that returns a list of tuples of sets of length p, where each set is a partition of the set S. e.g. equipartitions({0,1,2,3}, 2) --> [({0, 1}, {2, 3}), ({0, 2}, {1, 3}), ({0, 3}, {1, 2})].
However I am having some difficulty getting it to work properly for other cases since `itertools.products` will not concatenate the tuples of sets. Any advice or help on how to go about writing/fixing the function would be greatly appreciated. Below is my attempt thus far:

```
equipartitions_cache_d = {}
def equipartitions(S,p):
    global equipartitions_cache_d
    if len(S) % p != 0:
        raise ValueError("Set must be of a length which is a multiple of p")
    if equipartitions_cache_d.get((frozenset(S),p)):
        return equipartitions_cache_d[(frozenset(S),p)]
    else:
        if len(S) == p:
            equipartitions_cache_d[(frozenset(S),p)] = [S]
        else:
            gens = []
            combs = [set(s) for s in itertools.combinations(S, p)]
            for c in combs:
                gens += [s for s in itertools.product([c], equipartitions(S-c,p))]
            uniqgens = []
            for g in gens:
                if not any([all([x in q for x in g]) for q in uniqgens]):
                    uniqgens.append(g)
            equipartitions_cache_d[(frozenset(S),p)] = uniqgens
        return equipartitions_cache_d[(frozenset(S),p)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient (takes a lot of time for bigger inputs like `equipart(set(range(100), 5))`) but works.

```
def equipart(s, p):
    import itertools
    if len(s) % p != 0:
        raise ValueError("Set must be of a length which is a multiple of p")
    com = map(set, set(itertools.combinations(s, p)))
    res = list()
    for ia, a in enumerate(com):
        for il, l in enumerate(res):
            if not any([(a&x) for x in l]):
                res[il] = res[il] + (a, )
                break
        else:
            res.append((a, ))
    res = filter(lambda x: len(x) == len(s) / p, res)
    return res
```

Output:

```
In [94]: equipart({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 3)
Out[94]: 
[({3, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 5}),
 ({2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}),
 ({1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}),
 ({2, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}),
 ({4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}),
 ({2, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}),
 ({1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}),
 ({2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5}),
 ({2, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4}),
 ({3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4})]

In [95]: equipart({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 2)
Out[95]: [({1, 2}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}), ({1, 3}, {4, 6}, {2, 5}), ({1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5})]
```

**Edit:**

New method with single subset in multiple tuples.

```
def equipart(s, p):
    import itertools
    if len(s) % p != 0:
        raise ValueError("Set must be of a length which is a multiple of p")
    com = map(set, set(itertools.combinations(s, p)))
    res = [x for x in itertools.combinations(com, len(s)/p) if set().union(*x) == s]
    return res
```

Output:

```
In [37]: equipart({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 3)
Out[37]: 
[({3, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 5}),
 ({2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}),
 ({1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}),
 ({2, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}),
 ({4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}),
 ({2, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}),
 ({1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}),
 ({2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5}),
 ({2, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4}),
 ({3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4})]

In [38]: equipart({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 2)
Out[38]: 
[({1, 2}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}),
 ({1, 2}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}),
 ({1, 2}, {4, 5}, {3, 6}),
 ({5, 6}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}),
 ({5, 6}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}),
 ({1, 3}, {4, 6}, {2, 5}),
 ({1, 3}, {4, 5}, {2, 6}),
 ({4, 6}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}),
 ({4, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}),
 ({1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}),
 ({1, 4}, {3, 6}, {2, 5}),
 ({1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}),
 ({1, 5}, {3, 6}, {2, 4}),
 ({1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}),
 ({1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5})]
```

Comment: Mathematically this doesn't add up, shouldn't there be 15 tuples in the output for equipart({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 2)? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058972/double-factorial-number-of-possibilities-to-partition-a-set-of-2n-items-into) These are:
12 34 56; 12 35 46; 12 36 45; 13 24 56; 13 25 46; 13 26 45; 14 23 56; 14 25 36; 14 26 35; 15 23 46; 15 24 36; 15 26 34; 16 23 45; 16 24 35; 16 25 34;

Comment: @JamesHarrison ok, I thought one `subset` with `p` length can only be a part of one tuple, this is not the case, it can be a part of multiple tuples as long as tuples are unique. I have updated my answer and added this case.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir, Thank you for the second code. When I tried it, it returned the following error message: "TypeError: integer argument expected, got float" in line: "res = [x for x in itertools.combinations(com, len(s)/p) if set().union(*x) == s]". 
In order to solve it, I edited the code by converting "len(s)/p" to "int(len(s)/p)".